# OpenGl and Blender

Tags: opengl

Dear Blender Community,

The goal is object coordinates.

OpenGL provides information about view coordinates, normalized device coordinates, clip coordinates, eye coordinates, and object coordinates.

[image]

The OpenGL matrices:

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

The final object coordinates:

[image: Text]

where..

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Question**

How is my interpretation?

Cite:

1. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html#google_vignette
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749675/opengl-mouse-coordinates-to-space-coordinates/46752492#46752492

Comment: A picture having 90° angles calibrates field of view and aspect ratios for unknown cameras. In Blender prepare a photo with a cube or square, then finalize the two parameters. 

The near and far clipping calibration is from perspective lines, but not important.